# Should the method to sort a list modify it in-place or return a new object?

Tags: language-design, standard-library

Say I have a list class which has a `sort` method.

```
class List { // the standard library list class for a language
    // ...
    method sort {/*...*/}
    // ...
}
```

Should this method, when called, sort the list in-place or return a new sorted list? I don't know which is more efficient and which is more user-friendly/expected behaviour.

Comment: For the efficiency side of the question cs may be a better place to look. E.g. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3/why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice

Answer (score 12):

## Why not both?

Swift has a mutating method `.sort()`, and a method that returns a copy `.sorted()`. The former is only implemented for a couple of types like arrays, but the latter can be implemented for a lot of things.

Comment: Same deal for other languages. For Ruby - there's [Array#sort](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Array.html#method-i-sort) which returns a new array with sorted elements, and [Array#sort!](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/Array.html#method-i-sort-21) which returns the same array, sorted in-place. For Rust - AFAICT the protocol is to mutate in place; if you want a non-mutating version, you're expected to clone the array first. I expect there are other examples as well.

Comment: Python also has `v.sort()` (in place) and `sorted(v)` (sorted copy).

Comment: Kotlin's situation is the same: a `sort` on `MutableList` and `sorted` on `List`

Answer (score 5):

Returning a copy is more flexible.

This JavaScript implementation of a `List` class has both:

```js
    class List {
      constructor(a) {this.data=a;}
      sort() {return this.data.sort();}
      sorted() {return [...this.data].sort();}
    }
```

Creating a new `List` is simple:

```js
    x=['c','g','a','d','b'];
    y=new List(x);
```

The `sort()` method mutates not only `y.data` but also `x`:

```js
    console.log(y.data);
    console.log(y.sort());
    console.log(y.data);
    console.log(x);
```

If you use the `sorted()` method, `x` and `y.data` are left unchanged.

```js
    console.log(y.data);
    console.log(y.sorted());
    console.log(y.data);
    console.log(x);
```

`y.data` can be changed by assigning the returned array from `sorted()`:

```js
    y.data=y.sorted();
```

Answer (score 4):

## Functional but In-Place

Semantically returns a new copy, and then optimize it into an inplace operation according to the subsequent process.

### Reference

- [FBIP: Functional but In-Place Reuse Analysis](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2020/11/perceus-tr-v4.pdf)
- [FP²: Fully in-Place Functional Programming](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2023/05/fbip.pdf)

For FBIP sort, you can refer to `FP² chapter 4.2`.

Note that the unit of inplace/reuse analysis is not the `sort` operation, but the elements' allocate actions, which is more flexible and powerful.

### Who Use This Feature

- [Koka](https://koka-lang.github.io/koka/doc/book.html#sec-fbip)
- [Lean4](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4)

Comment: Koka is able to reuse constructors when they are not live, with seems to work nicely when mapping a tree, but will it work with sorting?

Answer (score 3):

## New Object

Mutable lists are known to cause bugs. It's annoying to deep-copy every time you want to do something. You could consider just not supporting mutable lists.

Comment: Mutable types aren't a problem if you use CoW.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

## In-place + a `copy` method for lists

This provides the efficiency benefits of in-place sorts, while creating a new sorted list is still possible (and convenient).